# Obsfucation of code in commercial product

Tags: obfuscation

Yesterday, my manager asked me to find and remove all references to 'previous incarnation of company' that appear in the binaries we produce for a product that we're launching in a few weeks.  This got me wondering why, in a compiled stand-alone binary, there's so much human-readable content, and whether there's a simple way to obsfucate it so that the program's internals aren't hanging out in the open, so to speak (at least to anyone who opens it with a text editor or greps the file contents).  Here are some examples of what I mean:

```
"WGL_3DFX_multisample               À       @      ð>Unknown OpenGL error
   GL_INVALID_FRAMEBUFFER_OPERATION"
```

"    Unable to close due to unfinalised statements   not an error    SQL logic error or missing database access permission denied    callback requested query abort  database is locked  database table is locked    out of memory   attempt to write a readonly database    interrupted disk I/O error  database disk image is malformed    database or disk is full    unable to open database file    table contains no data  database schema has changed String or BLOB exceeded size limit  constraint failed   datatype mismatch"

```
"flowChartDelay  flowChartDisplay    flowChartDocument   flowChartExtract    flowChartInputOutput    flowChartInternalStorage    flowChartMagneticDisk"
```

The majority of the file is human incomprehensible stuff like this, which is more what I'd expect from a binary:

```
"âÀÿ? ‰•þÿÿÇ…”þÿÿ    ë‹…”þÿÿƒÀ‰…”þÿÿ‹”þÿÿ;Mà}`‹U‹‚¨  ‹”þÿÿ¶ƒúuF‹E‹ˆ°  ‹•”þÿÿ·Q¯…ŒþÿÿÁè‰…Œþÿÿ‹M"
```

I figured out I could simply do a search and replace for 'string that we don't want' and replace it with random text of the same length and the program would run fine, which is possibly easier than making 500 edits to our source to bring it up to date with the current status of the company as a legal entity (there are a tonne of functions called `name_of_previous_company_foo())`, and also easier than trying to integrate some exotic obfuscation utility into our complex and propritary build system, but it's not an especially elegant solution, and I'd still like to know if there's a way to make our binaries into something more like a black box, where someone can't just open it with a text editor and see our function and class names.

Comment: For which language(s)?

Comment: Are we talking about an executable like elf or exe ? Upx might be a solution to this unless someone finds out about this. Upx compresses and encodes your binary

Comment: The executables are exe, elf, apk and mach-o, and the languages are C with some Java thrown in somewhere around the android side of things.  We have a large code-base that stretches back many years, and we're producing binaries for android, iphone, ios, linux and windows via a complex and hairy build system that takes our generic mostly-c code and creates platform-specific binaries with customer-specific features.  I tried upx, and it did exactly what I was looking for, but it couldn't handle apk files, so I'll need to find a solution for those.

Answer (score 0):

People build source code obfuscator tools for "commercial software" that can scramble strings and identifiers so they aren't easily read out of the binary, but are still usuable as the strings they intend to be.

Such obfuscators tend to be language specific, because they have to handle the fine detail of the language structure.

Google "Source Code Obfuscators" and you'll find many.